# Выполнить скрипт при заполнении оперативной памяти

Tags: apache, centos, bash

Centos 5.5необходим костыль, который при достижении объема заполненной оперативки, скажем, в 1,7Гб - перегружал апач.
идеи?..

Comment: очень желательно видеть решение, которое уже где-то работает и выполняет свою задачу а не "не пинайте, это мой первый в жизни скрипт"

Comment: как понятно, никто не может предложить вариант, работающий у него. я могу предложить свой, пишу не в первый раз и оно точно будет работать. нужно?

Comment: может быть поможет ulimit -v 1700000? Но это я из лиукса

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так)))

```
#!/bin/bashwhile [ : ]dox=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,9}'`x=`expr $x`y=`cat /proc/meminfo | grep Cached | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,9}' | head -n 1`y=`expr $y`z=$[`cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,9}'`-200]z=`expr $z`i=$[$x+$y]i=`expr $i`if [ $i -ge $z ]; then/etc/init.d/apache 2 restartelsesleep 180fidone
```

Comment: Прошу сильно не пинать, один из первых скриптов мной написанных)

Comment: этот скрипт выполняется в вечном цикле, что в свою очередь может завесить сервер.

Comment: Ну... если убрать цикл и ткнуть в крон - то пойдёт. И ещё, я бы поменял     egrep -o '[0-9]{1,9}' на     grep -o '[0-9]*'    grep Cached | egrep -o '[0-9]{1,9}' | head -n 1на     grep ^Cached | grep -o '[0-9]*'

Comment: покамест работает */15 * * * * /usr/sbin/httpd -k restartно мне такое костыльное решение категорично не нравится...

Comment: так в крон я имел ввиду скрипт kvazet'а, а не апач. только выкинуть цикл из него и рекомендовал свои правки.могу предложить свою интерпретацию, но в данном случае мои правки не критичны и пусть вся слава достанется kvazet'у )))

Answer (score 0):

А не лучше ли разобраться в проблеме - почему Апач перегружает память?

Comment: Может deivan админ, а внутренности могут вообще быть зенд-скомпилены или их просто дофига и разработчик сторонний. У меня была такая ситуация, правда я выбил себе сервак новый ))))

Comment: это уже тема для нового вопроса :)